# How to properly convert BigNumber on frontend to avoid case float and exponential errors?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I have function, which calculate big Numbers on frontend side (take 1% from input), and then pass data to contract

```
// like this
const input = new BigNumber(_input)
const result = input.multipliedBy(99).dividedBy(100)
return String(result.toFixed())
```

But sometimes I get error like this

> errors.js:85 Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid number value
>   (arg="_minReturn", coderType="uint256", value="39868830097469.8614",
>   version=4.0.44)

Or like this

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid number value
>   (arg="_minReturn", coderType="uint256",
>   value="1.1350120633522164e+23", version=4.0.44)

I would be very happy if you shared the best practices.

Answer (score 1):

```
const input = new BigNumber(_input)
const result = input.multipliedBy(99).dividedBy(100)
return toHex(new BigNumber(Math.floor(result)))
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add the big.js package to your project dependencies;
- import Big from 'big.js';

`const number1 = Big(numberOne);`